# cannot access properties of json objects inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array of objects like

```
[
   {
      "id":17368,
      "creationDate":1566802693000,
      "status":"InProgress",
      "type":"NEW",
      "agentType":"Master"
   },
   {
      "id":17368,
      "creationDate":1566802693000,
      "status":"InProgress",
      "type":"NEW",
      "agentType":"Master"
   },
   {
      "id":17368,
      "creationDate":1566802693000,
      "status":"InProgress",
      "type":"NEW",
      "agentType":"Master"
   },
   {
      "id":17368,
      "creationDate":1566802693000,
      "status":"InProgress",
      "type":"NEW",
      "agentType":"Master"
   }
]
```

**But when trying to access the object property 'id' using `console.log(array[0].id)` throws a "cannot read property id of undefined error"**

However just logging the first object with `console.log(array[0])` prints the object successfully.

```
{id: 17368, creationDate: 1566802693000, …}
```

Also printing the list of ids using `array.map(x => console.log(x.id))` prints the list of ids successfully .

I am in a situation where i need to access the first few specifically . Where am i going wrong ?

Comment: try with array[0][id]

Comment: Are you getting data for `array` using any ajax call?

Comment: @user2063635 — Why? The property appears to be called `id` and there is no variable of that name declared.

Comment: @user2063635 : tried that . throws reference id is undefined

Comment: @palaѕн --- yeah

Comment: You need to share that code also, like where are you putting `console.log(array[0].id)` inside callback or outside the callback?

Comment: @palaѕн --- and its being passed as props from parent to child component

Comment: can you add more code to be able to have more insight and help you out

Comment: Ajax response is being passed from parent to child component as property orders ```useEffect(()=> {
        console.log(props.orders[0].id);

    });```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this `console.log(array[0] && array[0].id)`

or you can use get from lodash-es like this:

```
 import { get } from 'lodash-es'

const id=get(array[0], 'id', '')
```

Comment: printing it using the first way works. but why is it so ?

Comment: array[0] && array[0].id means : if array[0] is true, then print array[0].id

Comment: it is a simple test just to ensure that the object is there and it is not undefined because when rendering the component it may that the array is not filled yet and that why you get undefined. please mark this answer as useful

Comment: was trying to print before the ajax call completed . just a simple check needed . thanks